# Running python script on C# and getting output continuously

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run a python script from C# and I want to get the output line by line and not at the end. I feel like I'm missing something important, but don't know what. This is what I have so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cmd = "C:/Users/user/Documents/script.py";
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe",
            Arguments = cmd,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        },
        EnableRaisingEvents = true
    };
    process.ErrorDataReceived += Process_OutputDataReceived;
    process.OutputDataReceived += Process_OutputDataReceived;

    process.Start();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
    Console.Read();
}

static void Process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

And the python code:

```
import time

for i in range(5):
    print("Hello World " + str(i))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Are we to assume that you are getting output, but you're getting it all at once?  This is not stated in the question.

Comment: I am getting output, but at the end of the 5 seconds.

Comment: By default `print` does not flush the output.  There are several ways of doing that, depending on your python version.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function

Answer (score 14, accepted):

change your python code to the following:

```
import time
import sys
for i in range(5):
    print("Hello World " + str(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

or just edit your c# code and use -u switch:

```
var cmd = "-u C:/Users/user/Documents/script.py";
```

When standard output it was being redirected, the event in C# wasn't being raised when a line was written on console because there were no calls to  stdout.flush;

Putting a stdout.flush() statement after each print statement made the events fire as they should and C# now captures the output as it comes.

Or you could just use -u switch.

Comment: This works perfectly. Apparently I didn't know about the flushing mechanism.

Comment: Note that if you don't want to modify the python code, there are alternative ways of accomplishing this.  See my link under your question.  the command-line argument `-u` will use unbuffered streams.

Comment: -u works perfect