# .NET Intercepted STDOUT from Python is always empty in Unity

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, process, ipc

I'm trying to use a Python program to send a continuous stream of information from one program to another, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379866/running-python-script-on-c-sharp-and-getting-output-continuously), but in byte form.

`pythonPath` and `pythonScript` are just the file locations of the script and `python.exe`.

#### C# code

```cs
public static void PythonKernel_Test() {
    Process pythonProcess = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() {
        FileName = pythonPath,
        Arguments = pythonScript,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    });
    Stream pythonStdOut = pythonProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        pythonStdOut.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
        Debug.Log(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer) + Environment.NewLine + BitConverter.ToString(buffer));
    }
    pythonStdOut.Close();
}
```

Although this is in Unity, you could just substitute `Debug.Log` for `Console.WriteLine()`.

However, even though I am spamming `stdout` with `SYNC`, nothing appears on the C# side. It does however, appear in the command prompt when ran from shell.

### Python code

```py
w = sys.stdout.buffer
while True:
    w.write(b"SYNC\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: why not just `sys.stdout.write(b"SYNC\n")` ?

Comment: I've been trying different IPC mechanisms that all incidentally use `write()` as their write functions, like pipes and sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a working sample to try out

```
public static void PythonKernel_Test()
{
    var pi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "python",
        Arguments = "test.py",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
    };
    var pythonProcess = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = pi,
    };

    pythonProcess.OutputDataReceived+= (s,e) => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OUT: {0}",e.Data);
    };
    pythonProcess.ErrorDataReceived+= (s,e) => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERR: {0}",e.Data);
    };

    pythonProcess.Start();
    pythonProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    pythonProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
    pythonProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

It will read the output asynchronously

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29753402/1744164

test.py

```py
import sys

while True:
    sys.stdout.write(b"SYNC\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: I'd like to do this synchronously if possible.

Comment: Look at the link I gave you, there is an example for sync and async

Comment: Oh, so you're right. I didn't see it. Either way: Both methods return literally nothing.

Comment: Well, a void method will return **void** which is in fact **nothing**

Comment: I meant `Read()`, `ReadLine()`, etc. are filling the buffers with nothing (and thus returning 0 always). Yeah I know the functions are void.

Comment: I tested the above code and it was working as expected, I will add the python code too. Do you forgot the `import sys`? Without that line I only get an output on the Error output

Comment: Looks like it works outside of Unity, but not inside Unity itself.